# computeArea() return [object object] in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Got into trouble when trying to compute the area of a rectangle

Here's [a link](http://web-9v2fudsqpo.treehouse-app.com/) to the website I created.

The rectangle has been properly drawn, but the calculation of area is wrong.

Below is my code in JavaScript:

```
  var Area;
  var areaPath;
  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.912106, 116.397346),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var rectBoundsLatlng = new Array;
    var rectBoundsLatlngPath = new Array;

    rectBoundsLatlng[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(39.907679, 116.342119),
    rectBoundsLatlng[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(39.950330, 116.394133),
    rectBoundsLatlngPath[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(rectBoundsLatlng[1].lat(),rectBoundsLatlng[0].lng()),
    rectBoundsLatlngPath[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(rectBoundsLatlng[0].lat(),rectBoundsLatlng[1].lng())

    var areaPath = [
      rectBoundsLatlng[0],
      rectBoundsLatlngPath[0],
      rectBoundsLatlng[1],
      rectBoundsLatlngPath[1],
      rectBoundsLatlng[0]
    ];

    Area = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea( areaPath );
    alert(Area);

   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hopefully there is someone who can help me with this.
BTW, the geometry library has been included already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the "new". change:

```
Area = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea( areaPath );
```

To:

```
Area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea( areaPath );
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1afjprk/2/)

Comment: Thank you! BTW, is it the area presented in m^2?

Comment: from the documentation: [To compute the area (in square meters) of a polygonal area, call computeArea(), passing the array of LatLng objects defining a closed loop.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance).  Also specified in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Comment: @geocodezip Nearly spent 2 days before I got here. Thanks you are life saver !!