# How can i calculate rectangle area in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am studying C# , google map api. and i want to draw click rectangle and calculate rectangle area.
this is my code:

```
function mode() {
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        var bounds = makeBounds(event.latLng, 200, 100);

        placeRec(bounds);
    });
}

function placeRec(bounds) {
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        editable: true,
        bounds: bounds,
        draggable:true
    });
}


function makeBounds(nw, metersEast, metersSouth) {
    ne = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(nw, metersEast, 90);
    sw = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(nw, metersSouth, 180);
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    sowe = bounds.getSouthWest();
    noea = bounds.getNorthEast();
}
```

I succeed draw click Rectangle in google map,
I want to know calculate Rectangle Area.

How do i have to do?

Thank you

Comment: This neither Java nor C# code.  It's Javascript.  Please update your tags to target the right audience that can answer your question.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Comment: possible duplicate of [computeArea() return (object object) in google map api v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331341/computearea-return-object-object-in-google-map-api-v3)